# ecdh-curve and tls cipher do not work together

Tags: tls, openvpn

most of my question are already answered by reading in this forum, but "one last thing" is still open.

I am running a OpenVPN server with the following security characters:

> SERVER (Raspbian Buster)
>   auth SHA512
>   auth-nocache
>   remote-cert-tls client
>   user openvpn
>   group openvpn
>   ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
>   cert /etc/openvpn/server/server.crt
>   key /etc/openvpn/server/server.key
>   tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/server/ta.key
>   dh none
>   ecdh-curve brainpoolP512r1
>   tls-version-min 1.2
>   cipher AES-256-GCM
>   ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-256-CBC
>
> CLIENT (iPhone App)
>   tls-version-min 1.2
>   remote-cert-tls server
>   auth SHA512
>   cipher AES-256-GCM
>   auth-nocache

Everything works fine so far and the client can connect. But the missing link is the tls-cipher. With the following cipher my server starts, but the client cannot connect - of course I used the same ciphers for server and client.

> tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA256

The result is the following server status:

> TLS error: The server has no TLS ciphersuites in common with the client. Your --tls-cipher setting might be too restrictive.
>   OpenSSL: error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher
>   TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
>   TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
>   TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

I tried some more tls-cipher like

> tls-cipher TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   but the server did not start with that configuration.

Which tls-cipher can be used for client and server?

Comment: You want ECDHE, not DHE, and you want Curve25519 / X25519, not brainpool. The cipher suite name part that is RSA or ECDSA must match the type of key in the certificate you're using. You want GCM and you don't want CBC. Also, do you need to specify the cipher list using openssl names or RFC names? See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html

Comment: Ok, so I assumed the ecdh-curve and the cipher have to match, but did not find any information so far. Could you please give me a concrete example of a very secure curve and cipher, which would work?

Comment: The best recommendation is ECDHE with X25519, RSA (2048 is big enough), AES GCM (128 is enough). Use chacha20poly1305 on mobile devices without hardware AES.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the right portion of your cipher spec.
In TLS 1.2 the cipher spec contains several parts corresponding to different settings:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

- The first part is obvious: this is TLS
- The second part (`ECDHE` or `DHE`) defines the key exchange used: elliptic curve based diffie-hellman or "normal" RSA based diffie-hellman (it also can be omitted to disable forward secrecy, but **don't do that**)
- The next part tells which key type the certificate uses, it can be `ECDSA` for an elliptic curve or `RSA` for an rsa key, you must pecify the right one that corresponds to your certificate key
- the remaining parts after the WITH define which symmetric cypher to use once authentication and key exchange are done. In this example it uses 128bit `AES` in `CBC` mode with `SHA256` for message authentication. You should use AES in GCM mode wherever possible because it does encryption and authentication in one step rather than using a separate MAC.

Using that knowledge it becomes clear that you have to use at least something like

```
tls-cipher TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```